# Tracking model changes in after_commit :on => :create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to track changes to model on after_commit when a record is created? I have tried using dirty module and was able to track changes when the record was updated, but when record is created changes are not recorded.

Comment: How could there be any changes when something is just being created?

Comment: The fields that go from nil to a valid value.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't use the rails `changed?` method, as it will always return false. To track changes after the transaction is committed, use the `previous_changes` method. It will return a hash with attribute name as key. You can can then check if your attribute_name is in the hash:

```
after_commit :foo

def foo
 if previous_changes[attribute_name]
   #do your task
 end
end
```

Comment: thanks! And to check if the hash contains your attribute, you could do something like this `if @item.previous_changes.has_key?('attribute_name')`